# how to parse the XML tag's attribute?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I have a question in parsing XML. How can I parse out the value of tag's attributes. For example:

```
<location lat="35.24" lon="-97.44" timezone="UTC" city="Norman" region="OK" country="US" zipcode="73019" offset="0" local_offset_hours="-5">
```

I wanna get the region. But not sure how? please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of guides for parsing XML. Here is one example: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/08/04/objective-c-parsing-an-xml-file/

Just try googling around and you'll find some answers.